# How to cache HTML pages from Wordpress to avoid querying the database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like to know how to delivery to the browser CACHED html pages so to avoid querying the database often. So basically I need the equivalent of OUTPUT CACHE in .Net, but should work in PHP and WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin [wp-super-cache](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) promises just that. Never used it myself but it should work.